# Trouble with drawing tree in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl

Getting more errors again this time, except this time it's on the webgl side instead of the mathy algorithm side.

My previous post was just about drawing a simple 2d recursive tree. The thing I'm trying to do now is to draw a tree at the location of the mouseclick, and with red lines if left click, blue if right. I fixed my previous problem and was able to get the tree to show up in my previous build of the program. However, now a tree doesn't even show up when I click on the canvas. When I console log the array where the points are stored however, all the points seem to be there. I think I'm missing something, but I don't know webgl enough to know what that may be.

I have made a working program that can draw different colored points depending on mouse click, at the mouse position, but I'm still not experienced enough to figure out what I have in that program that is allowing it to work and why this current program isn't able to display anything.

my current program:

```
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
    'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
    '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
    'precision mediump float;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
    '}\n';

var m = 0;

function main() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    // Get the rendering context for WebGL
    var uniform1i = 0;

    var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    if (!gl) {
        console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
        return;
    }

    // Initialize shaders
    if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
    }

    // // Get the storage location of a_Position
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
    var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
    if (!u_FragColor) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
        return;
    }

    // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press
    canvas.onmousedown = function (ev) { click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) };

    // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // Clear <canvas>
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 1, m);
}


function click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) {
    var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width / 2) / (canvas.width / 2);
    y = (canvas.height / 2 - (y - rect.top)) / (canvas.height / 2);


    if (ev.button == 0) {
        var depth = 4;
        gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);// Red
        //red tree, 4 steps, length 50, halved each step

        // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
        var n = initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y);
        if (n < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
            return;
        }
        m = n;

    }
    if (ev.button == 2) {
        var depth = 6;
        //blue tree, 6 steps, length 40, halved each step
        gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);// Blue
        // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
        var n = initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y);
        if (n < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
            return;
        }
        m = n;
    }
}


function initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y) {
    let start = [];
    let points = createPoints(x, y, 0.4, 4, Math.PI / 2, start);
    console.log(points);
    var vertices = new Float32Array(points);
    let n = points.length / 2; // The number of vertices
    // Create a buffer object
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    if (!vertexBuffer) {
        console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the buffer object to target
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    // Write date into the buffer object
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return -1;
    }
    // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

    return n;
}

//var points = [x, y];
//var angle = 0;
//var prevPoints = [];
//var prevPointIndex = 0;
function createPoints(x, y, length, depth, angle, points) {
    if (depth > 0) {
        //draws line
        let x2 = x + length * Math.cos(angle);
        let y2 = y + length * Math.sin(angle);
        points.push(x, y, x2, y2);

        //draw left branch;
        createPoints(x2, y2, length / 2, depth - 1, angle + Math.PI / 4, points);

        //goes back
        //points.push(x2, y2);

        //draw right branch
        createPoints(x2, y2, length / 2, depth - 1, angle - Math.PI / 4, points);

        //goes back
        //points.push(x2, y2);
        //console.log(points);
        return points;
    }
    return;
}
```

my bets are that I'm missing something in the main or click functions, but I'm posting everything because I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What is `gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 1, m);` intended to do? Probably it has to be `gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, m);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted only calls `gl.drawXXX` one time in main so it's never going to draw anything ever again.

You have things set up so when the mouse is pressed `click` will be called but `click` never calls `gl.drawXXX`

Further, every time `click` is called you make a new buffer with a new set of points. That is not the normal way to use WebGL. The normal way is to setup your points once (once per thing you want to draw) and then use matrices to change position, orientation, scale.

I suggest you read some other tutorials on WebGL. [This one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) kind of does what you're doing now but it follows up with how to [change position](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-translation.html), [orientation](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html), and [scale](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-scale.html), followed by [how to do it with matrices for more flexibility](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html). It also covers [drawing multiple things](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

In any case to fix your code as is you need to draw after changing the vertices

```js
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE = 
    'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
    '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
    'precision mediump float;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
    '}\n';

var m = 0;

function main() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    // Get the rendering context for WebGL
    var uniform1i = 0;

    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    if (!gl) {
        console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
        return;
    }

    // Initialize shaders
    if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
    }

    // // Get the storage location of a_Position
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
    var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
    if (!u_FragColor) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
        return;
    }

    // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press
    canvas.onmousedown = function (ev) { click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) };

}


function click(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor) {
    var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width / 2) / (canvas.width / 2);
    y = (canvas.height / 2 - (y - rect.top)) / (canvas.height / 2);

    if (ev.button == 0) {
        var depth = 4;
        gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);// Red
        //red tree, 4 steps, length 50, halved each step

        // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
        var n = initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y);
        if (n < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
            return;
        }
        m = n;

    }
    if (ev.button == 2) {
        var depth = 6;
        //blue tree, 6 steps, length 40, halved each step
        gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);// Blue
        // Write the positions of vertices to a vertex shader
        var n = initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y);
        if (n < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
            return;
        }
        m = n;
    }
    
    // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // Clear <canvas>
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, m);
    
}


function initVertexBuffers(gl, x, y) {
    let start = [];
    let points = createPoints(x, y, 0.4, 4, Math.PI / 2, start);
    console.log(points);
    var vertices = new Float32Array(points);
    let n = points.length / 2; // The number of vertices
    // Create a buffer object
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    if (!vertexBuffer) {
        console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the buffer object to target
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    // Write date into the buffer object
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return -1;
    }
    // Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

    return n;
}

//var points = [x, y];
//var angle = 0;
//var prevPoints = [];
//var prevPointIndex = 0;
function createPoints(x, y, length, depth, angle, points) {
    if (depth > 0) {
        //draws line
        let x2 = x + length * Math.cos(angle);
        let y2 = y + length * Math.sin(angle);
        points.push(x, y, x2, y2);

        //draw left branch;
        createPoints(x2, y2, length / 2, depth - 1, angle + Math.PI / 4, points);

        //goes back
        //points.push(x2, y2);

        //draw right branch
        createPoints(x2, y2, length / 2, depth - 1, angle - Math.PI / 4, points);

        //goes back
        //points.push(x2, y2);
        //console.log(points);
        return points;
    }
    return;
}
main();

//----
function initShaders(gl, vSrc, fSrc) {
  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vSrc, fSrc]);
  gl.program = program; // THIS IS EXTREMELY BAD AND WRONG CODE!!!
  gl.useProgram(program); // THIS IS ALSO WRONG!
  return program;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

There are many issues with the code

1. `gl.program` is not a thing. Whatever book or tutorial you're learning from that is a horrible, bad, and wrong thing to do. WebGL programs usually have multiple shader programs so a function like `initShaders` needs to return the created program so that you can call it multiple times with different vertex shader source and fragment shader source to make multiple programs. It should not hack one created program on to the webgl context where it doesn't belong.

   Note: even though I implemented `initShaders` since you didn't supply it it's clear from your code it was doing `gl.program = gl.createProgram`. That's nonsense code. It's common to have multiple programs.
2. calling `gl.useProgram` in `initShaders` is also arguably wrong. (It's clear again since it's not called anywhere in your code that your version of `initShaders` was doing that. Again it makes no sense since in a normal WebGL page you'd have multiple shaders so you'd need to call `gl.useProgram` multiple times.
3. The tutorial you're reading looks old as it's concatenating strings for GLSL. The easiest way to make GLSL is to use multi-line template literals

   ```
   var VSHADER_SOURCE = `
       attribute vec4 a_Position;
       void main() {
         gl_Position = a_Position;
       }
   `;
   ```

   so much easier
4. It's calling some function `getWebGLContext`. No need for anything like that. Just use `canvas.getContext('webgl')`
5. the call to `gl.drawArrays` has `m` in the wrong place. The correct way to call `gl.drawArrays` is `gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, vertexCount)`. Offset is almost ways 0. There is no 4th parameter.

Please consider reading some better tutorials like the ones linked above.